# Dot product of arrays that are members of the same list

Tags: sparse-arrays, dot

Lets say I have a list of n arrays:

```
n=3;
list = Table[RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {2, 2}], n];
```

I would like to calculate the matrix corresponding to:

```
list[[1]].list[[2]].list[[3]]
```

I was thinking of Dot, as

```
Dot[a,b,c]=a.b.c
```

and then I thought that Flatten can be used to drop the outer brackets. However, it seems I cannot use Flatten as

```
Dot[Flatten[list, 1]]
```

does not produce the correct result.

```
Dot[Flatten[list, 1]] == list[[1]].list[[2]].list[[3]]
```

gives False.
Essentially how do you take the dot product of arrays (and sparse arrays of large dimensions) that are members of the same list?

Comment: Are you looking for ``Dot @@ list``? This is a shorthand for ``Apply[Dot, list]``.

Comment: Also `Fold[Dot,list]`.

Comment: Also, `MapThread[Dot, Transpose@{list}][[1]]` or `MapApply[Dot, {list}][[1]]`.